# perl -f check fails to identify file

Tags: perl, file

I have a perl script that goes through a folder with a couple of thousand files.

When I started writing the script I was unaware of the perl File::Find functions, so in order to list all the files in the structure I used something along the line of:

```
open (FILES, "$FIND $FOLDER -type f |");
while (my $line = <FILES>) {...}
```

Now however I figured I would try doing this from perl instead of launching a external program.
(No real reason to do this change other than wanting to learn to use File::Find.)

Trying to learn the semantics of File::Find find function I tried a few things on the command line and compared the output to that of find.

Oddly enough there is 1 file that the program find finds but the perl function skips.

Find works:

```
machine:~# find /search/path -type f | grep UNIQ
/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_015.MOV
/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_145.MOV
/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/Thumbs.db

machine:~# find /search/path -type f | wc -l
    6439
```

Perl fails:

```
machine:~# perl -e 'use File::Find; find(sub { print $File::Find::name . "\n" if -f }, "/search/path");' | grep  UNIQ
/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_145.MOV
/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/Thumbs.db

machine:~# perl -e 'use File::Find; find(sub { print $File::Find::name . "\n" if -f }, "/search/path");' | wc -l
    6438
```

Changing to exclude folders rather than include files works:

```
machine:~# perl -e 'use File::Find; find(sub { print $File::Find::name . "\n" unless -d }, "/search/path");' | grep  UNIQ
/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_015.MOV
/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_145.MOV
/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/Thumbs.db
```

Only difference between the files is the size:

```
machine:~# ls -l /search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/
total 4213008
-rw-rw-r--    1 user users    4171336632 May 27  2012 movie_file_015.MOV
-rw-rw-r--    1 user users    141610616 May 27  2012 movie_file_145.MOV
-rw-rw-r--    1 user users       20992 May 27  2012 Thumbs.db
```

Perl on the machine in question is old but not ancient:

```
machine:~# perl -version

This is perl, v5.8.8 built for sparc-linux

Copyright 1987-2006, Larry Wall

Perl may be copied only under the terms of either the Artistic License or the
GNU General Public License, which may be found in the Perl 5 source kit.

Complete documentation for Perl, including FAQ lists, should be found on
this system using "man perl" or "perldoc perl".  If you have access to the
Internet, point your browser at http://www.perl.org/, the Perl Home Page.
```

Is this a known bug or something?

Or am I hitting some size limit of '-f'? The file is almost 4gb and the largest in the selection.

Or is my test (if -f) poorly chosen?

**EDIT** [trying to stat files]:

Big file fails

```
machine:~# perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(stat("/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_015.MOV"));'
```

Small file works

```
machine:~# perl -e 'use Data::Dumper; print Dumper(stat("/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_145.MOV"));'
$VAR1 = 65024;
$VAR2 = 19989500;
$VAR3 = 33204;
$VAR4 = 1;
$VAR5 = 1004;
$VAR6 = 100;
$VAR7 = 0;
$VAR8 = 141610616;
$VAR9 = 1349281585;
$VAR10 = 1338096718;
$VAR11 = 1352403842;
$VAR12 = 16384;
$VAR13 = 276736;
```

Binary 'stat' works on both files

```
machine:~# stat /search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_015.MOV
  File: "/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_015.MOV"
  Size: 4171336632  Blocks: 8149216    IO Block: 16384  Regular File
Device: fe00h/65024d        Inode: 19989499    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1004/user)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2012-10-03 18:11:05.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2012-05-27 07:23:34.000000000 +0200
Change: 2012-11-08 20:44:02.000000000 +0100

machine:~# stat /search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_145.MOV
  File: "/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_145.MOV"
  Size: 141610616   Blocks: 276736     IO Block: 16384  Regular File
Device: fe00h/65024d        Inode: 19989500    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1004/user)   Gid: (  100/   users)
Access: 2012-10-03 18:26:25.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2012-05-27 07:31:58.000000000 +0200
Change: 2012-11-08 20:44:02.000000000 +0100
```

Also:

```
machine:~# perl -e 'stat("/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_145.MOV"); print $! . "\n";'
Bad file descriptor

machine:~# perl -e 'stat("/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_015.MOV"); print $! . "\n";'
Value too large for defined data type
```

**EDIT2**:

```
# perl -V | grep "uselargefiles|FILE_OFFSET_BITS"
config_args='-Dccflags=-DDEBIAN -Dcccdlflags=-fPIC -Darchname=sparc-linux -Dprefix=/usr -Dprivlib=/usr/share/perl/5.8 -Darchlib=/usr/lib/perl/5.8 -Dvendorprefix=/usr -Dvendorlib=/usr/share/perl5 -Dvendorarch=/usr/lib/perl5 -Dsiteprefix=/usr/local -Dsitelib=/usr/local/share/perl/5.8.8 -Dsitearch=/usr/local/lib/perl/5.8.8 -Dman1dir=/usr/share/man/man1 -Dman3dir=/usr/share/man/man3 -Dsiteman1dir=/usr/local/man/man1 -Dsiteman3dir=/usr/local/man/man3 -Dman1ext=1 -Dman3ext=3perl -Dpager=/usr/bin/sensible-pager -Dstatic_ext=B ByteLoader GDBM_File POSIX re -Dusemymalloc -Uuselargefiles -Uafs -Ud_csh -Uusesfio -Uusenm -Duseshrplib -Dlibperl=libperl.so.5.8.8 -Dd_dosuid -des'
useperlio=define d_sfio=undef uselargefiles=undef usesocks=undef
```

Problem "solved":

```
machine:~# perl -e 'stat("/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_015.MOV"); print $!{EOVERFLOW} . "\n";'
92
machine:~# perl -e 'stat("/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_145.MOV"); print $!{EOVERFLOW} . "\n";'
0
```

Works:

```
# perl -e 'use File::Find; find(sub { print $File::Find::name . "\n" if -f or ( $!{EOVERFLOW} > 0 and not -d) }, "/search/path");' | grep UNIQ
/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_015.MOV 
/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/movie_file_145.MOV 
/search/path/folder/folder/UNIQ/Thumbs.db
```

Comment: Curious.  Can you [stat](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat.html) the file and show us what it returns?

Comment: The stat seems to fail aswell, I'll edit the post and add the results of my tests.

Comment: Fail?  As in, it returns an empty list??

Comment: Yes, the troubling file gets the empty list. The smaller file in the same folder get a bunch of data using the same call.

Comment: I think that -f doesn't have any size limit

Comment: and what is `$!` after the stat fails?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on [a bit](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Perl/perl.beginners/2004-03/0608.html) of [Googling](http://www.justskins.com/forums/about-stat-problem-49666.html), it looks like your perl interpreter has not been compiled with [large file support](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl56delta.html#Large-file-support), causing `stat` (and any file tests that rely on it internally, including `-f`) to fail for files larger than 2GB.

To check whether this is the case, run:

```
perl -V | grep "uselargefiles|FILE_OFFSET_BITS"
```

If your perl has large file support, the output should show something like `uselargefiles=define` and `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`.  If it doesn't, it's likely that you perl does not support large files.

It may be somewhat puzzling why large file support is needed even for just `stat`ing files.  The underlying problem is that the 32-bit version of the [stat(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) system call, rather than returning a bogus size, simply fails with `EOVERFLOW` if applied to a file larger than 2GB:

> "**EOVERFLOW**
>
> > (**stat**()) *path* refers to a file whose size cannot be represented in the type *off_t*. This can occur when an application compiled on a 32-bit platform without *-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64* calls **stat**() on a file whose size exceeds *(1<<31)-1* bits."

Technically, receiving that error *should* be enough to indicate that the named file does exist (although I guess it could be a truly humongous directory too), but perl is not smart enough to realize that — it just sees that the stat failed, and so returns nothing.

(*Edit:* As ikegami correctly notes in the comments, `-f` returns `undef` rather than 0 or 1 if the stat(2) call fails, and sets `$!` to the error code that caused the failure.  So, if you don't mind assuming that all directory entries with size > 2GB are files, you could do something like `-f $_ or (not defined -f _ and $!{EOVERFLOW})` to check for it.)

Comment: It doesn't return nothing; it returns undef (error) instead of 0 (not a plain file) and sets `$!` to `EOVERLFLOW`. You can check for an overflow by checking `$!{EOVERFLOW}` when `-f` returns undef.

Comment: You, sir, are very much correct. You may cash in a beer whenever it would be possible for me to deliver. ;) Thank you!

Comment: @azzid: No problem. We can see about the beer if I ever happen to have some reason to be near Linköping. :)

Comment: Perl wouldn't be able to know that the named entry is a file though, because the `stat` failed so it doesn't have the mode bits to perform that test. It knows the name exists, but doesn't know if it's a regular file, directory, or what..